# SharePoint Online modern layout and PopUps / Dialogs

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog

Since SharePoint Online Modern Layout it isn't possible to have links and buttons to open a link in a popup/dialog. There is no possibility to add own code and the web part for buttons allows no javascript inside.

But how can I open a PDF, a web site etc in a dialog by using the SharePoint Online modern layout?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to embed [PnP IFrameDialog control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/IFrameDialog/) which could display web page in a dialog in the SPFx extension.

For more information, please refer to:

https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/24/popup-documents-using-pnp-iframedialog-control-in-spfx/

https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/modaldialog/src/webparts/modaldialog/components/Modaldialog.tsx

Similar issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0db7ccb-3be1-4e8b-9a04-55a96d251a49/open-modal-dialog-from-spfx-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint